# How is the `'Old` attribute in a **Post** contract handled for access types that might got deallocated inside the function or procedure?

Tags: ada, spark-ada

Assume having the following setup:

```
type My is new Integer;
type My_Acc is access My;

procedure Replace(Self : in out My_Acc; New_Int : Integer)
  with Pre => New_Int /= Self.all, Post => Self'Old.all /= Self.all;
```

**Note:** Code above might not be fully valid, but I hope the concept is understandable.

Now what happens if `Unchecked_Deallocation()` is used on `Self` inside `Replace`
and a new Integer is allocated and set to `Self` (This should result in Self'Old pointing to a now invalid memory location)?

Does Ada keep kind of a snapshot where `Self'Old` points to the previous memory location, but before `Unchecked_Deallocation()` is executed?

If `Self'Old` would get invalid for use in the Post contract, how could you still access the previous value? Is it possible to create a manual snapshot in the Pre contract that can then be used in Post? Maybe it can be achieved using Ghost_Code?

I want to make everything in Spark, in case that changes something.

**Edit:** Fixed `Self` to `in out` as mentioned by Simon Wright.

**Edit:** Fixed type of `Self` to allow `null`

Comment: Unchecked_Deallocation sets the access object to `null`. Since your access subtype has the `not null` constraint, this will fail.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed my code snippet to better reflect what the code could do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [ARM 6.1.1(26ff)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-6-1-1.html#p26) it says

> Each X'Old in a postcondition expression that is enabled denotes a constant that is implicitly declared at the beginning of the subprogram body, entry body, or accept statement.
>
> The implicitly declared entity denoted by each occurrence of X'Old is declared as follows:
> ...
>
> X'Old : constant S := X;

... in other words, nothing fancy is expected, just a straight copy of (in this case) `Self`: *not* `Self.all`.

So, if your `Replace` deallocates `Self`, then `Self’Old` is a dangling reference, and erroneous.

I suggested previously that changing the postcondition to

```
Post => Self.all'Old /= Self.all;
```

would be safe; why wouldn’t that meet your requirements? is there something going on you haven’t told us about?

---

Note the subtle difference between `Self’Old.all` and `Self.all’Old`. The first one takes a copy of `Self` as it was before the call, which gets dereferenced after the call (by which time it’s pointing into hyperspace), while the second one dereferences the prior `Self` and copies the integer value it finds there; on return that’s still valid.

Comment: Thanks for your research. Is your solution with `Post => Self.all'Old /= Self.all;` comparing the Integer values? I thought this is not possible if `Replace` deallocates `Self` since the old Integer object does not exist anymore.

Comment: Added some explanation at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

It may be that the latest versions of SPARK support access types; it used not to, at all.

First, your `Not_Null_My_Acc` needs to be a subtype of `My_Acc`, unless you meant it to be a type in its own right.

Second, you can’t deallocate `Self` inside `Replace` and allocate a new value; `Self` is in-mode, & hence not writable.

Third, you can’t apply `’Old` to `Self`, because

```
warning: attribute "Old" applied to constant has no effect
```

What you can say is

```
Post => Self.all'Old /= Self.all;
```

Comment: A my bad. I meant to set `Self` to `in out`. With `in out` it should now be possible to set `Self` to `null`.

Comment: Looks to me as though that doesn’t work - that is, my test program fails at the postcondition

Comment: I will try an alternative approach with Ghost variables. If this works I will add it as possible answer/workaround. Thanks so far for your feedback.